# Call methods on fragment - every object is null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following problem:

I have one Fragment, which implements a specified interface.

```
    @Override
public void sensorStatusChanged(double bearing, double pitch, double rotation) {
    if (radarView != null) {
        radarView.setBearing((float) bearing);
    }
    ....
}
```

The ParentActivity handles the Location-Listener and tries to inform the fragment that sensorData has changed.

At this part, I have the following behaviour: The method gets called, but the radarView is null. I'm 100% sure, that the radarView is not null. When I set some breakpoints into this code, the only part where the radarView is null, is inside of methods, which are called from the activitiy and not from the fragment itself.

I'm a total beginner in dealing with fragments (started today), so I think I'm doing something wrong.

How can I solve this behaviour?

Cheers

Comment: I'm not very experienced too, but I think you are making a mistake trying to implement the Interface in the Fragment class.
Fragment only defines the Interface and let the Activity to implement it.

Comment: And how can I send information from the parent-activity to the fragment?

Comment: I don't want to inform my parent-Activity. Actually, my parent-Activity deals with location-data and everytime, the data has changed, the fragment should be notified... But when I try to send the data to the fragment, every object inside of my fragment is null... which is definitely not true :(

Comment: Inside your Fragment  call `getActivity()` so you can have access to any method from your Activity ( and get the data you want ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found the mistake myself: I've created a fragment in onCreate of the activity. But when I change fragments, I recreated the fragments, without removing the listener of the old fragment..